# Faint but visible monochrome edge detection

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, edge-detection, vision

I am trying to detect a visible edge that seperates two different types of texture.
The problem is, although the texture difference is quite visible, we couldn't manage to detect the edge that seperates two regions with acceptable accuracy (e.g. few pixels) using GLCM or Gabor filters.

I am questioning whether these algorithms are suitable for this. I just wonder whether there would be any algortihm recommendations. Thanks.

In the [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5qDY.png), the edge extends from near center top to bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

This is not feasible with current state of the art. "the texture difference is quite visible" is a false impression.